# How can I compile a TypeScript file using a Gradle task?

Tags: typescript, gradle, tsc, gradle-node-plugin

I have an OpenAPI schema, and I want to make sure that it produces valid TypeScript code.

Using the [Gradle Node Plugin](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/) I can generate TypeScript code from the `openapi.yml` file by calling `openapi-typescript` in an npx task.

```kotlin
import com.github.gradle.node.npm.task.NpxTask
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.parseSpaceSeparatedArgs

plugins {
    id("com.github.node-gradle.node")
}

val openApiGenerateSchemaDTs by tasks.registering(NpxTask::class) {
    description = "Generate TypeScript OpenAPI Schema"

    val openApiYml = layout.projectDirectory.file("src/main/resources/openapi.yml")
    inputs.file(openApiYml)

    val schemaDTsFile = temporaryDir.resolve("schema.d.ts")
    outputs.file(schemaDTsFile)

    command.set("openapi-typescript@5.4.1")
    args.set(
        parseSpaceSeparatedArgs(
            "${openApiYml.asFile} --output $schemaDTsFile"
        )
    )
}
```

This correctly generates TypeScript code based on the schema. However, the generated code might be invalid. To verify that it is, I want to use `tsc` to compile the code.

I can do this from the command line with this command:

```bash
npx \                      
  --yes \ # required, otherwise npx command won't run if TypeScript isn't installed
  -p typescript@4.7.4 \
  tsc build/tmp/openApiGenerateSchemaDTs/schema.d.ts \
  --listFiles \
  --noEmit \
  --strict
```

When I try and recreate this command in a Gradle `NpxTask`

```kotlin
import com.github.gradle.node.npm.task.NpxTask
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.parseSpaceSeparatedArgs


val openApiCompileSchemaDTs by tasks.registering(NpxTask::class) {
    val openApiSchemaDTs = openApiGenerateSchemaDTs.map { it.outputs.files.singleFile }
    inputs.file(openApiSchemaDTs)

    command.set("--yes -p typescript@4.7.4 tsc")

    args.set(
        parseSpaceSeparatedArgs(
            "${openApiSchemaDTs.get()} --yes --listFiles --noEmit --strict"
        )
    )
}
```

Then I get an error

```
> Task :openApiCompileSchemaDTs FAILED
/var/folders/wl/2bzbzknd077dyh2ww_6xjty80000gp/T/npx667633524.sh: line 2: .../build/tmp/openApiGenerateSchemaDTs/schema.d.ts: Permission denied

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':openApiCompileSchemaDTs'.
> Process 'command 'npx'' finished with non-zero exit value 126
```

If I set the command to be `tsc` and move the options into `args`...

```kotlin
val openApiCompileSchemaDTs by tasks.registering(NpxTask::class) {
    val openApiSchemaDTs = openApiGenerateSchemaDTs.map { it.outputs.files.singleFile }
    inputs.file(openApiSchemaDTs)

    command.set("tsc")

    args.set(
        parseSpaceSeparatedArgs(
            "--yes -p typescript@4.7.4 ${openApiSchemaDTs.get()} --yes --listFiles --noEmit --strict"
        )
    )
}
```

Then I get another error

```
> Task :openApiCompileSchemaDTs FAILED

                                                                               
                This is not the tsc command you are looking for                
                                                                               

To get access to the TypeScript compiler, tsc, from the command line either:

- Use npm install typescript to first add TypeScript to your project before using npx
- Use yarn to avoid accidentally running code from un-installed packages
```

I'm sure it's just a case of setting the correct command and arguments, but I've tried a few different combinations with no success.

##### Versions

- Gradle 7.5.1
- Gradle Node Plugin 3.4.0